# drawing lines and circles on screen using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw some lines and circles on the screen using of matplotlib.  I do not need the X axis and Y axis.  Is this possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the axes with `axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)` or by using `axis('off')`.

Example:

```
from pylab import *

gca().get_xaxis().set_visible(False) # Removes x-axis from current figure
gca().get_yaxis().set_visible(False) # Removes y-axis from current figure

a = arange(10) 
b = sin(a)
plot(a, b)
show() # Plot has no x and y axes
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want axes, and are happy to work in the range 0-1:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

fig = plt.figure()
fig.patches.append(mpatches.Circle([0.5, 0.5], 0.25, transform=fig.transFigure))
fig.show()
```

There are a couple of benefits to using @Dhara's solution. The primary being you can use a data coordinate system which automatically scales to your data, but if you just want to draw a couple of shapes, my solution works pretty well.

Some useful documentation if you go down the route I have explained:

- http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Circle
- http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D
- http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle